# Website stress test in Python - Django

Tags: python, django, http, testing, load

I'm trying to build a small stress test script to test how quickly a set of requests gets done.

Need to measure speed for 100 requests.

Problem is that I wouldn't know how to implement it, as it would require parallel url requests to be called. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why build it?

There are several available.

1. For a single url and many requests try [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html)
2. For multiple urls and random tests try [siege](http://freshmeat.net/projects/siege/)

Answer (score 19):

Also, there is an awesome open-source pure-python distributed and scaleable [locust](http://locust.io/) framework that uses [greenlets](http://greenlet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It's great at simulating enormous amount of simultaneous users.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to stay within the Python framework you might try Corey Goldberg's [Pylot](http://www.pylot.org/) or its successor [multi-mechanize](http://testutils.org/multi-mechanize/).

Answer (score 4):

Although this question is quite old, I'd like to point out a nifty tool about this problem.
The tool is [funkload](http://funkload.nuxeo.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this exactly the type of testing you were looking for but [BrowserMob](http://browsermob.com/performance-testing) uses [Selenium](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/Home) to do browser load testing. It works as if many browsers were pounding on your site simultaneously. It isn't created for any specific framework and should work on pretty much any web app.